# How to type a method with an interface as parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to define a method signature where a parameter should conform to an interface.

```
interface Command {}

class HelloCommand implements Command {
  constructor(public readonly name: string) {}
}

type HandleCommandFn = (command: Command) => Promise<any>;

const handleHello: HandleCommandFn = (
  command: HelloCommand
): Promise<string> => {
  return Promise.resolve(`Hello ${command.name}`);
};
```

I get the following error from the compiler:

```
src/index.ts:9:7 - error TS2322: Type '(command: HelloCommand) => Promise<string>' is not assignable to type 'HandleCommandFn'.
  Types of parameters 'command' and 'command' are incompatible.
    Property 'name' is missing in type 'Command' but required in type 'HelloCommand'.

9 const handleHello: HandleCommandFn = (
```

I also tried the following variations :

```
type HandleCommandFn = <C extends Command>(command: C) => Promise<any>;
```

```
type HandleCommandFn = <C extends Command = Command>(command: C) => Promise<any>;
```

**UPDATE**

With the help of answers below, I managed to get the following piece of code (my goal was to define a type-safe method decorator) :

```
interface Command {
  getDescription(): string;
}

type HandleCommandFn<C extends Command = Command> = (
  command: C
) => Promise<any>;

function HandleCommand<C extends Command = Command>(
  target: Object,
  propertyKey: string | symbol,
  descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<HandleCommandFn<C>>
): void {
  const method = descriptor.value;
  if (method) {
    // Do something
  }
}

class HelloCommand implements Command {
  constructor(public readonly name: string) {}

  public getDescription(): string {
    return "Say hello";
  }
}

class HelloCommandHandler {
  @HandleCommand // OK
  public execute(command: HelloCommand): Promise<string> {
    return Promise.resolve(`Hello ${command.name}`);
  }

  @HandleCommand // Error (wrong parameter type)
  public execute2(command: string): Promise<string> {
    return Promise.resolve(`Hello ${command}`);
  }

  @HandleCommand // Error (wrong return type)
  public execute3(command: HelloCommand): string {
    return `Hello ${command.name}`;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
interface Command {}

class HelloCommand implements Command {
    constructor(public readonly name: string) {}
}

type HandleCommandFn<C extends Command = Command> = (
    command: C
) => Promise<any>;

const handleHello: HandleCommandFn<HelloCommand> = (
    command
): Promise<string> => {
    return Promise.resolve(`Hello ${command.name}`);
};
```

Comment: I can confirm this works. My goal was to define a type-safe method decorator. I updated the question with the complete working code.

Answer (score 1):

This is because function arguments are contravariant.
Consider this example:

```js
interface Command { }

interface HelloCommand extends Command {
  name: string
}

declare var command: Command

declare var helloCommand: HelloCommand

command = helloCommand // ok , is assignable
```

It is intuitively, `helloCommand` is assignable to `command` because it is more specific. And it is easy to understand why subtype is assignable to supertype.

But if you look at this example, things are not obvious anymore:

```js
let commandFn = (command: Command) => void 0

let helloCommandFn = (command: HelloCommand) => void 0

commandFn=helloCommandFn // error, is not assignable anymore
```

FUnction with `HelloCommand` argument (subtype of Command) is not assignable anymore to function with `Command` (supertype).

This is how contravariance works. Direction of inheritance has changed is opposite direction.
What you are trying to do is unsafe, or in other words - `unsound` behavior.

In order to trick compiler you can add extra generic:

```js
type HandleCommandFn<T extends Command> = <U extends HelloCommand>(command: T & U) => Promise<any>;

// ok
const handleHello: HandleCommandFn<Command> = (
  command
): Promise<string> => {
  return Promise.resolve(`Hello ${command.name}`);
};
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer which pointed me to the following article : https://medium.com/@michalskoczylas/covariance-contravariance-and-a-little-bit-of-typescript-2e61f41f6f68 I was bot familiar with covariance and contravariance, I now understand it.

Comment: Please check my question and all related links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covaraince-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc . You will find a lot more information